# operations on arrays in python from memory perspective

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to understand the memory allocation in the following operation:

```
x_batch,images_path,ImageValidStatus = tf_resize_images(path_list, img_type=col_mode, im_size=IMAGE_SIZE)
x_batch=x_batch/255;
x_batch = 1.0-x_batch  
x_batch = x_batch.reshape(x_batch.shape[0],IMAGE_SIZE[0]*IMAGE_SIZE[1]*IMAGE_SIZE[2])
```

what I am interested in is the `x_batch`, this is a multi-dim numpy array `(100x64x64x3)`
where 100 is the number of images and 64x64x3 is the dimensions of the image.

what is the maximum number of copies of the images located inside the memory at one point of time.
in other words, how exactly the operations `(x_batch/255)` , `(1-x_batch)` and `x_batch.reshape` are happening from memory perspective.

my main concern is in some cases I am trying to process 500K images at the same time, if I will make multiple copies of these images in the memory, it will be very difficult to fit everything in the memory.

Comment: Certainly memory errors occur.  Each `=` produces a temporary buffer - except the reshape.

Answer (score 0):

I see "tf" in your code, so I am unsure if you are asking about tensors or arrays. Lets assume you are asking about arrays. In general, arrays are written to memory once and then manipulated. For example,

```
import numpy as np
data = np.empty((1000,30,30,5))  #This took up 1000*30*30*5*dtype_size bytes (plus epsilon). 
data.reshape((1000,30,150))      #Does nothing but update how numpy accesses the array.
data += 1                        #Adds one to all the entries in the array. 
data = 1-data                    #Overwrites the array with the data of 1-data.
x    = data + 1                  #Re-allocates and copies the whole memory.
```

As long as you don't change the array size (re-allocate the memory), then numpy operates very quickly and efficiently on the data. Not as good as tensorflow, but very very fast. In place adding, functions, operations, are all done without using more memory. Things like appending to the array could cause problems and make python rewrite the array in memory.